# How to display current date/time with timezone in LotusScript?

Tags: lotusscript

Same output as Now() but with timezone.

Have tried the following but returned wrong results.

```
Dim datetim As New NotesDateTime( Now() )
Messagebox datetim.TimeZone
Messagebox datetim.GMTTime
```

Basically the output I want to see is like this

```
07/11/2013 01:06:29 PM (Correct GMT, in which case +8:00 in my system)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With property [ZoneTime](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_ZONETIME_PROPERTY.html)

```
Messagebox datetim.ZoneTime
```

you get date, time and zone like `07/11/2013 01:06:29 PM CEDT`.

In case you need to adjust to a certain time zone then use [convertToZone](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_CONVERTTOZONE_METHOD.html) before. Behind the link is a good example too.

Comment: Thank you. It's the closest I can get. Probably I could code a workaround like a select case statement and get the substr after AM/PM and convert it to my liking.

Answer (score 0):

I think the call of convertToZone is required before this will work, even if you are staying in the current zone.

Call dateTime.ConvertToZone(dateTime.TimeZone, True)
Print (dateTime.ZoneTime )

That's my experience.